# When does the compiler need access to a library?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, linker

Lets say I have 3 projects:

- Project Program -> compiles into an executable

  - References Audio, Tweakbar
  - Additional Dependencies: nothing
  - Additional Library Dependencies: nothing
- Project Audio

  - wrapper around fmod, compiles into .lib
  - Additional Dependencies: fmodex_vc.lib
  - Additional Library Dependencies: $(SolutionDir)\libs\fmod\lib
- Project TweakBar

  - wrapper around AntTweakBar, compiles into .lib
  - Additional Dependencies: AntTweakBar.lib
  - Additional Library Dependencies: $(SolutionDir)libs\AntTweakBar\lib

Now, the issue is that I am getting the following compile error:

fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'AntTweakBar.lib'

This error can be resolved by placing the path to that lib file in the project settings of "Program"

What I want to know is why I need to have the path to this lib there? fmod works perfectly fine without such a path.

Comment: There is no setting named "Additional Library Dependencies".  If you mean "Directories", no, that doesn't have an effect in linking Program.

Comment: @HansPassant Additional Library Dependencies is under Project properties -> Linker

Answer (score 0):

Because the libraries are only required when the executable is created; at this point, all the libraries are linked into the executable.

Apparently, the VisualStudio IDE doesn't automatically "promote" libraries used by other libraries upwards to the actual application, so you have to do that manually.

Comment: If this is the case, then why does it work for FMOD? I can play music perfectly fine without giving the "Program" project a path to fmodex_vc.lib

Comment: In fact its not just FMOD, I dont provide a path to many other libraries: SDL, freetype, freeimage, glu32, glew32 ...